# undefined con jquery ajax y php

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Estoy tratando de enviar una variable por `GET` con jQuery a PHP y hacer una consulta la BD MySQL.

Pero me dice que esta `undefined` la variable.

Pero solo me pasa cuando la meto adentro del `success function()`;
Después del evento `click`.

Pero si saco el método `$.ajax()` si me imprime todo normal por consola.

```
$("#solicitudes").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: "../../model/parcel/despliegue_notifications.php",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (response) {
        let despliegueNoti = JSON.parse(response);
        let template = `<div class="header-despliegue" id="header-despliegue">
            Notificaciones
            </div>`;

        despliegueNoti.forEach((recorroDatos) => {
            template += `<div class="body-despliegue" id="body-despliegue" tomoDato="${recorroDatos.id}" >                                                                       
                ${recorroDatos.nombre} ha enviado una solicitud para ${recorroDatos.tipo}
                </div>`;
        });

        $("#despliegue-notificacion").html(template);
            mostra_ocultar();
        },
    });
});

$(document).on("click","#body-despliegue", function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "../../model/parcel/request-data-notifications.php",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (response) {
        let elementoRequerido = $(this)[0];
        let id =$(elementoRequerido).attr("tomoDato");
        console.log(id);
        },
    });

});
```

¿Por que me esta lanzando ese `undefined`?

Comment: Veo varias llamadas a $.ajax, cuál en concreto te da el error? Podrías indicar lo que has intentado mediante snippets de código para poder verlo, porque es un poco confuso tal cual lo explicas. Además, el código está mal indentado, cuando pongas código intenta seguir una correcta indentación, porfavor.

Comment: Un poco confuso el codigo. Pero hasta donde puedo ver estas usando $(this)[0] dentro de la función del callback success y this hace referencia al caller de esta funcion. guarda $(this)[0] en una variable antes de ejecutar ajax. Ejemplo var $this = $(this)[0]; y dentro del success utilizas $this como variable de dato.

Comment: Hola que se supone que trae esto  let elementoRequerido = $(this)[0];

Comment: ¿Qué variable es la que esperas recibir en PHP? Porque en la petición AJAX no la estás enviando.

Answer (score -1):

Hola no se si te entiendo muy bien pero cuando pones this dentro de la función $.ajax el this hace referencia a la función  $.ajax no al click, tienes que ponerlo fuera para que funcione.

```
$(document).on("click","#body-despliegue", function(){

        let elementoRequerido = $(this)[0];
        let id =$(elementoRequerido).attr("tomoDato");
        

       $.ajax({
       url: "../../model/parcel/request-data-notifications.php",
       type: "GET",
       success: function (response) {
           console.log(id);
        },
    });

});
```

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que hacen estas dos líneas de código: `let elementoRequerido = $(this)[0]; let id =$(elementoRequerido).attr("tomoDato");`? Cuando el contexto es confuso, conviene pedir aclaraciones a OP antes de aventurarse en una respuesta. La pregunta y el código son muy confusos.